# PDF reader for latex sublime text on arch

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, latex

i am using manjaro ,
i already downloaded sublime-text,and Tex-live .
on windows i used to run sumatra as pdf reader and it as great .
no i cannot find a repository for sumatra pdf for arch so any alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise you to install Okular: https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/okular/ It's a great little PDF reader.
`sudo pacman -S okular`to install.